# Flutter project's Android folder shows an error

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile

After updating my gradle version I can see that my android folder have 2 problems , but when I go in android folder I can't find them. See the picture bellow.
My android builds  (debug , release , appbundle)  , all  working fine , but I am confused abound seeing  errors on my android folder.
Please help me to understand what's the problem ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RyrM.png)

I did ***flutter clean*** , but still can see these errors on VS code.

Comment: You can ignore that error. Or simply restart the editor. Error will be no more.

Comment: @AdityaPatil  I see that error about a week. And during that week I restarted my IDE many times.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the similar issue when I did flutter upgrade as well as gradle upgrade.
Somehow upgrading never works perfectly in flutter for Android section and bound to cause  errors when building APKs.

So what I did was downloaded all new SDKs and created a new flutter project and copied all existing folders there to have a fresh project. Worked fine.